# How do I enable apt-get tab suggestions on my server?

Tags: server, apt

On my desktop typing `python-` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> offers suggestions of installable packages that are prefixed `python`. My server doesn't have this ability, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `bash-completion` and put this line in your ~/.bashrc (but check first if there is a similar line first):

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

Note that it will only take effect in new terminals you open from now on. To take effect in the current terminal source your `~/.bashrc`

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Actually... you can just type `source ~/.bashrc` in the command line and it will reload the `.bashrc` system.  You won't need to relogin.

Comment: Put your suggestion in the text of the answer, thank you.

Comment: I don't have edit powers :/